# Insert field value as "number" type

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection which has some existing data and there is a particular field which is causing a little problem for me.

The field value is like this,

```
 "user_id" : 106962662714214320000
```

So, when I get the type of this field,

```
> typeof db.cbRel.findOne().user_id
number
```

Now, I am inserting data to mongo via pymongo. This `user_id` is a static value. It has same value for every document.

But I get this error on `user_id` field,

```
MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints
```

How can I insert this value in mongo  via pymongo?

Comment: you can use `Decimal128()` from Mongodb 3.4. More details here: [pymongo decimal128](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/decimal128.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried it. The data is inserted but its inserted as NumberDecimal

Comment: Can you show the way you attempted to store it? I've just tried to insert a document with your `user_id` and I haven't got an error

Comment: Hey, did you try using pymongo? Can you show me the way you did it?